# How to loop through an array calling jquery.each on each element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to loop through an array of elements and then validate each instance of each element. This is how I am doing it:

```
var elements = ["h1","h2","h3","h4","p","strong","label","span","a"];
function targetZWS(){
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        var item = $(".page-content "+elements[i]);
        $(item).each(function() {
            checkElement(this);
        });
    }
}
```

This throws a warning that I am creating a function inside a loop, how do I avoid this?

Comment: would making a `checkElements` function that loops over all of your items and calling it from inside the loop still cause a warning?

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have such a warning. You must be using a linter. You might be able to configure the linter to ignore that line. Or get rid of the loop by changing your code to `$(".page-content").find(elements.join(',')).each(...)`. Or change `checkElement` to accept an index as first argument and the element as second argument and use `item.each(checkElement)`. Or both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying too hard :)  JQuery allows you to enter multiple options in a single selector.

```
function targetZWS(){
    $("h1,h2,h3,h4,p,strong,label,span,a").each(function() {
            checkElement(this);
        });
    }
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Use `.each()` to loop through the array as:

```
 $(function() {
  var elements = ["h1","h2","h3","h4","p","strong","label","span","a"];
  $.each(elements, function(index, value) {
    alert(value);
    var sel = ".page-content" + value
    var item = $("sel");
        $(item).each(function() {
            checkElement(this);
        });
  })
})
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/mayank_shubham/su7j0qjx/2/)**